# using google maps api without a key

Tags: javascript, google-maps

The [instructions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key) for v.3 of the Google Maps API say that I

> should load the Maps API using an API key

Curiously it says I *should...*, rather than I *must....*. Anyhow, at the moment, I am not using an API key simply because (as far as I can remember) there was no mention of an API key when I was writing the code that calls this API.

Should I go back and add an API key to the URL that loads the API? It seems to work fine without the key, so I don't have any particular incentive to do this.

Comment: I thought it does only work without a key on localhost?

Comment: @Luke: That's how it was with the API V2.

Comment: Now you must use an API key but there is a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148097/google-maps-api-without-key/38809129#38809129

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're actually required to *not* have a key if you're a business user. [Here's](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key) a quote from Google:

> Google Maps API for Business developers must not include a key in their requests. Please refer to Loading the Google Maps JavaScript API for Business-specific instructions.

Normal users, however, will be fine with or without a key, although Google recommends having a key so you can monitor the API usage. [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#keysystem) is a quote verifying this:

> The Google Maps JavaScript API V3 does not require a key, but there are benefits to using one.

Comment: Your quote says that business users *must not* use a key, and that's because they get a client ID instead.

Comment: Oh wow... sometimes I'm forced to question my intelligence. Thanks, I edited the post. +1 on your answer by the way.

Answer (score 2):

You only need a key if you want to use [the API  management console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) to restrict access, collect usage statistics, etc. So, a key is recommended but not required.
See [Obtaining an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key)

Answer (score 0):

In Api version 2 a key is required to run gmap out of localhost
in the API v3 a key is not required