# Google maps stopped working when I changed URL of page

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I changed the URL of a page on a website. That page had a google map embedded on it, using the following code:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" 
    async defer></script>
```

However, since changing the URL of the page; the map no longer works. I guess the URL of the original page must be stored somewhere with Google, but I cannot find where. Does anyone have an idea where I could find it ?

Comment: try in the api manager

Comment: Look at the javascript console, it should be telling you that you are missing the (now required on new domains) API key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps API without key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148097/google-maps-api-without-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go to you app on google's developer's console and add your url there
https://console.developers.google.com

Comment: I did have to do to the above URL, however I did not have to add my url there. Instead I get an API key and added it as follows:   <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

I did have to do to the above URL, however I did not have to add my url there. Instead I get an API key and added it as follows:

```
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
```